# Add custom attribute for rows when using ngfor

Tags: angular

I have a table definition like this

```html
<tr *ngFor="let pl of pEpics">
    <td>{{pl.WiId}}</td>
    <td>{{pl.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{pl.ProjectCode}}</td>
    <td>{{pl.Domain}}</td>
    <td>
       <span class="badge bg-primary">ADO : {{pl.AdoStatus}}</span>
       <span class="badge bg-warning">KIP : {{pl.KipStatus}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But for  every row, I need to add a value attribute like this

```html
<tr *ngFor="let pl of pEpics" value="here I need the pl.id"`>
```

Here I need `pl.id`

Could you please help to get that attribute with id as value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how is it done with Angular:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let pl of pEpics" [attr.value]="pl.id"`>
```